# Is there a validation rule for "not present"?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, laravel

I need to check if the key is not set in the array using Laravel validator.

That would be the complete opposite of the "required" validation rule.

Basically the array will be passed to update method if it passes the validation and I want to make sure one column will not be updated.

Is there a way to check if the value "is not present"?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I'm currently using Laravel 5

**EDIT:**

I managed to write my own validation rule by calling Validator::extendImplicit. However I get $value as null to my validation function both when I set it to null or when I don't set it at all. Is there a way to check if the value is set?

Comment: It might be that you are approaching this the wrong way. Why would a key/value be present in the array that should not be present? Possibly some defensive programming inside your update function is better in this case.

Comment: I just wanna make sure that noone would pass a value to the column I don't ever want to be updated. Currently the update is only applied in one location so I can unset the value manually if needed, but in the future there might be more cases and I want the validator to prevent this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I found a solution:

```
$validator->extendImplicit('not_present', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return !array_key_exists($attribute, $this->data);
});
```

I'm not calling extendImplicit statically because the Validator class object is injected to the controller of my class.

I need to access $this->data ($this referring to the Validator object) to make sure the key doesn't exist in the array being validated.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the @MaGnetas answer I came up with this 2 rules that can be applied on any model.
I'm using Laravel 5.4 so putting this lines on your `AppServiceProvider.php` should work.

**The first approach** (`extendImplicit` and `array_key_exists`)

```
Validator::extendImplicit('not_present', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    return !array_key_exists($attribute, $validator->getData());
});
```

Ussing `$validator->getData()` we could use the Validator statically.

**The second approach** (`extend` and `false`)

```
Validator::extend('not_present', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    return false;
});
```

You could use `extend` because we don't need the rule to be executed if the data has not the property (because that's exactly what we want right?)

On the docs:

> By default, when an attribute being validated is not present or contains an empty value as defined by the required rule, normal validation rules, including custom extensions, are not run. [more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules)

**Important**:  The only difference is that using `extend`, empty strings will not run the validation. But if you have setting `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` on your middleware (which AFAIK is the default option) there will be no problem

Answer (score 1):

No there is no build in validtion rule for this, but you can create your own validation rule.

The simplest way to do this:

```
    Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
     // Do some stuff
    });
```

And check if key exists.
More information:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: It looks like if I extend the validator with my own custom rule it only gets "applied" if the value is present in the array and it is not null. So still if I set the key to NULL the rule doesn't work and my column gets updated.

Comment: extendImplicit solves this. The rule is always applied, even if the attribute isn't there. However both setting it to NULL or not setting it at all has the same effect - $value is null

Comment: Thanks once again for your answer. It lead me to the working solution after all.

Comment: you are welcome. I dont like to give the complete solution. so know you can feel good, because you solved it by your own, with just a hint ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for the not_present logic in 7.x apps (applicable for all versions), remember that you can simply use the validated data array for the same results.

```
    $validatedKeys = $request->validate([
            'sort' => 'integer',
            'status' => 'in:active,inactive,archived',
        ]);

    // Only update with keys that has been validated.
    $model->update(collect($request->all())->only($validatedKeys)->all());
```

my model has more attributes  but only these two should be updatable, therefore I too were looking for an `not_present` rule but ending up doing this as the results and conceptual logic is the very same. Just from another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old but you can also use

```
'email' => 'sometimes|required|not_regex:/^/i',
```

If the **email** is present in the request, the regex will match any characters in the request and if the email is an empty string but is present in request the **sometimes|required** will catch that.

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 8, there are validation rules for prohibited fields. Here is an example

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'is_minor' => true,
    'tos_accepted' => true
], [
    'tos_accepted' => 'prohibited_if:is_minor,true'
]);
```

[Prohibited Validation Rules in Laravel](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-prohibited-validation-rules)

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-prohibited)